# Using SASS & reference for OOCSS

Tags: css, sass, less, oocss

Usually i use **LESS** for my projects but now im trying to go with **SASS**.

In LESS i do things like this

```
.module {
  background-color: blue;

  &-title {
    color: black;
  }

  &-type-2 {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

and the output CSS will be

```
.module { 
  background-color: blue;
}

.module-title {
  color: black;
}

.module-type-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

In SASS wont work, there is someway to do it in SASS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Sass 3.3, you can do that with the following syntax:

```
.block{
    &__element {
      // ...
    }
    &--modifier {
      // ...
    }
}
```